# Higgs Boson abundance in the universe

Tags: cosmology, standard-model, higgs

What's the Higgs boson abundance in the universe, in $\%$? In total? Does it even make sense? I cannot find any estimate on the internet.

Comment: How exactly do you define "abundance" for an unstable particle? On the face of it, the answer to your question would be "0".

Comment: In % of what: number? mass? period before decay? And compared to what: bosons? all particles? all matter (including dark matter)?

Comment: The OP is asking whether the question 'even makes sense' so he's aware of his lack of knowledge in the subject...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Higgs boson is one of the components along with the Goldstone bosons in two doublets of scalar fields. The three Goldstone bosons couple to the $Z,~W^\pm$ to introduce a longitudinal component to their dynamics, which corresponds to mass. The remaining particle couples to nothing. It has a mass of $125\,\mathrm{GeV}$ and requires considerably more energy to be produced in sufficient quantity. In addition the Higgs particle has a lifetime of about $10^{-22}\,\mathrm s$. The gamma factor for the colliding protons is about $\gamma=10^4$ and even if there is a gamma factor that dilates the life of the Higgs particle it is only to maybe about $10^{-19}\,\mathrm s$.

The universe is very cold, about $3\,\mathrm K$ and this means the average energy of systems is only about $10^{-5}\,\mathrm{eV}$. Compare that to the energy needed to produce the Higgs particle. It would require a remarkable place to produce Higgs particles, and in some sense we might say the LHC is one of them. Since the end of the first $3$ seconds into the big bang there have been few energy systems that can produce Higgs particles. Also the particle is highly unstable. I think these are enough to make the case there are very few Higgs particles in the universe. At least they do not constitute a large percentage of the universe.

Comment: As an aside: what are the two doublets you mention?

Comment: The doublets are pairs of scalars. I was a bit unclear on the role of Goldstone fields which are absorbed.  I edited this to clarify that.